# Can 2 linearly indipendent vectors belonging to $\mathbb{R}^3$ be considered a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Our professor told us that a set of vectors must belong to $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: Well, legally, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  You must pick a representative copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ inside of $\mathbb{R}^3$ before you can say something like $\{\langle 1,0, 0 \rangle, \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle \}$ is a basis of "$\mathbb{R}^2$".

Comment: Do you know what $\mathbb{R}^2$ means?

Comment: Can three floors in a 7-floor building be considered a 3-story building?

Comment: @Randall: The long arm of the law has a longer reach than I remember! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set of 2-tuples $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$. This not even a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^3$, because $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the set of 3-tuples $(a,b,c)$.

However, if you have two linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then they span a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is necessarily isomorphic to *every* two-dimensional vector space over the real numbers. You can prove this for the case here by constructing the invertible linear map that takes $v_1$ and $v_2$ to $w_1$ and $w_2$, where $w_1$ and $w_2$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.